# Can I change the registry to point a profile at an existing profile?

Tags: windows-10

A couple days ago I ran into an issue on Windows 10 where my system files were corrupted and SFC/DISM.exe were not able to fix the issue, so I reinstalled Windows, choosing the option to keep my existing files and data. This doesn't seem to have worked perfectly - while all my old data (`Documents`, `AppData`) is still present in `C:\Users\Andrew`, my profile is using a new `C:\Users\Andrew.COMPUTERNAME` directory.

My question is, can I just edit the registry to point the profile at `C:\Users\Andrew`?  Only one Andrew profile shows up when my computer starts, and there's only one entry in the registry under `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList`.

I'm backing up any important files and creating an additional admin account in case this all goes wrong obviously.

Thanks!

Comment: "My question is, can I just edit the registry to point the profile at C:\Users\Andrew?" - This is a poor solution to this problem.  It would be better to just migrate the files to the new profile.  You can then take ownership of the old profile directory, delete it, then if you want to rename the current profile allowing Windows to generate the new profile directory.  You can force this to happen by linking a Microsoft Account to your profile then immediately create a new local account.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! A couple questions, probably highlighting my lack of knowledge: Would migrating the files be as simple as deleting the `Andrew.COMPUTERNAME` directory and renaming the `Andrew` directory to `Andrew.COMPUTERNAME`? And, is there a way to rename the profile without linking a Microsoft Account? Or can I use a throwaway account for this? I definitely want to end up with a local, unlinked account.

Comment: Also, any chance you could elaborate on why this solution would be better? To my untrained eye, it seems like it would be kind of fragile - I assume somewhere within `AppData` a lazy programmer saved off a raw path which will break when the files are migrated.

Comment: Well your solution will result in permission issues.  The entire point of using Windows to create the profile directory is to update the registry key.  No; Your applications will not have a problem if you migrate your files manually.  If they do complain that would be a separate question anyways and would happen with your solution also.

Comment: If you provide a screenshot of the ACL for your old user profile. I would be willing to document an answer for you.

Comment: I'd love to take a screenshot of my ACLs but unfortunately I haven't a clue how to do that, and google isn't being much help. Any chance you could explain that to me? Thanks again for all your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Copying AppData in full from the old to the new profile seemed to mess things up, so I just made a new profile and am copying stuff from AppData as needed. Seems to be working fine, at some point in the future I'll delete the old profiles and (possibly) rename the new one.

Comment: I was trying to collect the information to write an answer that avoided the problems you ran into.